# how to make a slider which has a label can show above the handle with pyside2

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

The current value could displayed immediately above the slider,such like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJqkp.png)

Thanks so much!

I had try like it but it show not good enough.

Here is my codes:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSlider, QLabel
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)
        self.slider.setGeometry(30, 40, 100, 30)
        self.slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("50")
        self.label.setGeometry(140, 40, 30, 30)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QSlider')
        self.show()

    def changeValue(self, value):
        self.label.setText(str(value))
        self.label.move(self.slider.x() + value, self.slider.y() - 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I Made three changes.

**[change1]**

Changed the w of the slider to adjust the amount of movement of the label and slider.

**[change2]**

Display the label above the slider before moving the slider. The first code needed to move the slider so that the label appeared above the slider.

**[change3]**

Optional. I made the label appear slightly above the slider.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSlider, QLabel
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)
        #change1: change w(third argument) from 100 to 120
        self.slider.setGeometry(30, 40, 118, 30)
        self.slider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("50")
        self.label.setGeometry(140, 40, 30, 30)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QSlider')
        self.show()
        #change2: Set the initial position of the label above the slider 
        self.label.move(self.slider.x() + 50, self.slider.y() - 30)

    def changeValue(self, value):
        self.label.setText(str(value))
        #change3: move label position up(20 to 30)
        self.label.move(self.slider.x() + value, self.slider.y() - 30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```